# Can we link two separate apps(under same firebase project) to two different GA4 Properties

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-4

I have one Firebase account where created two apps both are android app, now I want them to connect with two different GA4 Properties.

I have tried connecting them but not able to do so, can anyone help on this?